# How to use named Mutex

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, mutex, streamwriter

I'm trying to use Mutex to handle different process/application to write on same file.

This is my code

```
 ILogTest logTest = new LogTest(new FileLog());
 logTest.PerformanceTest();


    public class ILogTest
    {
            public void PerformanceTest()
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < this.numberOfIterations; i++)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Thread threadC = Thread.CurrentThread;
                        threadC = new Thread(ThreadProc);
                        threadC.Name = i.ToString();
                        threadC.Start();
                        threadC.Suspend();
                        threadC.IsBackground = true;
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        throw new Exception("errore");
                    }
                }
            }

            private void ThreadProc()
            {
                try
                {
                    log.Write("Thread : " + Thread.CurrentThread.Name.ToString());
                    this.log.Write("Thread : " + Thread.CurrentThread.Name.ToString());
                    this.log.Write("Thread : " + Thread.CurrentThread.Name.ToString());
                    this.log.Write("Thread : " + Thread.CurrentThread.Name.ToString());
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    throw new Exception("errore");
                }
            }
    }
```

FileLog is an implementation of ILogTest.

Write method :

```
public void Write(string message)
    {
        try
        {
            rwl.WaitOne();
            try
            {
                string tID = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);

                sw.WriteLine(sev.ToString() + "\t" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm:ss", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture) + "\t\t"  + System.Reflection.Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().GetName().Name + "\t" + Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture) + "\t" + tID + " \t " + message);


                sw.WriteLine("------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Cannot write to file " + ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                rwl.ReleaseMutex();
            }
        }
        catch (ApplicationException)
        {
        }
    }
```

FileLog main :

```
public FileLog()
    {
        try
        {
            rwl.WaitOne();
            string filePath = Path.GetTempPath() + "Test.txt";
            if (!File.Exists(filePath))
            {
                swa = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write);
                sw = new StreamWriter(swa);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Cannot open or create file " + ex.Message);
        }

        try
        {
            if (sw == null)
            {
                swa = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write);
                sw = new StreamWriter(swa);
            }

            sw.AutoFlush = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Cannot write to file " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Trying simulate it, it doesn't write anything to file, only create it..
I don't know why.
Could anyone help me? thanks

Comment: Wouldn't file locking be better? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.lock(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @AdamBenson That would require all other threads/processes that attempt to write simultaneously to catch and handle the `IOException` that is raised when the file is currently locked. Depending on the contention that might not really be ideal.

Comment: Consider using log4net's FileAppender, with the [InterProcessLock](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/html/T_log4net_Appender_FileAppender_InterProcessLock.htm) locking model. Don't reinvent the wheel if you don't have to. (You can at least use [their implementation](https://github.com/apache/log4net/blob/fa13c71e628fd0a59880ecb50e79dc0d5724fa39/src/Appender/FileAppender.cs#L723) to see how it can be done.)

Comment: @Christian - hmmm didn't realize C#'s implementation was that bad. It's been a while since I used file locking in C++ but I definitely remember being able to wait for a file lock (I remember that because I deadlocked a whole TV station and took them off air with badly implemented file locks ...) LockFileEx (Win32 API) will wait if you ask it to: https://aljensencprogramming.wordpress.com/2015/05/06/file-locking-with-win32/

Answer (score 2):

The `FileLog` constructor calls `rwl.WaitOne()` which acquires the mutex (I'm assuming `rwl` is a `Mutex` object), but never calls `rwl.ReleaseMutex()`.

Thus, every thread that calls `Write()` blocks on its call to `rwl.WaitOne()` because the mutex is still owned by another thread.

You will need to release the `Mutex` in the `FileLog` constructor so that other threads can acquire it.

Also, you have a call to `threadC.Suspend();` in `PerformanceTest`; unless there is code that resumes the threads, they will never finish running.